# Cuda.is_available() False on VSCode .ipynb but True on JupyterLab

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook, pytorch, gpu

I want to train a VGG model on a gpu, because I have many images (137 099), and I need the process to go faster.

For this, I have a notebook: test.ipynb, on VSCode. My gpu is on a  cluster (SLURM) where I am connected by ssh via remote-ssh with VSCode.

I am working with a conda environment env2, Python3.7.12, torch 1.8.1+cu101, torch.version.cuda == 10.1

In my first cell, I do

```
import torch

print(torch.cuda.is_available())

DEVICE    = torch.device("cuda:0" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")
```

and I get

```
False

DEVICE = 'cpu'
```

It looks like the system can't access to the gpu, and the training of my VGG is indeed very slow.

Howevever, if I do !nvidia-smi on my notebook, I can see the gpu (TITAN X Pascal)

Now I try the same with a python file test.py instead of the notebook test.ipynb (still on VSCode with env2) I have

```
torch.cuda.is_available() = True,
```

and the training gets much faster.

And if I run test.ipynb with JupyterLab, I also get

```
torch.cuda.is_available() = True,
```

So it looks like VSCode cannot access the gpu from the notebook (test.ipynb), but can from a python file (test.py) even if I am using the same python Kernel (env2) for both files. This might come from VSCode since it works well on jupyterlab.

Does anyone know where does it come from?

Remark:

```
print(sys.executable) 

 > /home/manon/.conda/envs/env2/bin/python
```

both for test.py and test.ipynb files

Comment: Please provide more detailed debugging details. Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually figured it out.
I had first to create a tunnel, so that I could run my script with a Jupyter kernel using a remote jupyter server. I created the tunnel with:

```
jupyter notebook --ip localhost --port 3001 --no-browser
```

This command gave me an URI:

http://localhost:3001/?token=8afee394ef093456

Then I selected a jupyter remote server by cliking on "Jupyter Server:Local" button in the VSCode Status bar (you can also use "Jupyter: Specify local or remote Jupyter server for connections command" from the Command Palette)

and copied the URI obtained previously in: "Enter the URI of the running Jupyter server".

After this, everything worked fine

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).